# Eclipse : GLib-ERROR

Tags: java, c, memory-management, shared-libraries, allocation

I have an JAVA application for the fingerprint scanning and fingerprint matching.For matching the finger prints I am using the [libfprint](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/libfprint/) library.I have done all the settings related with the library.

The basic functions like initialization of library is work fine in the application.Now am trying to allocate the memory for the image using the function `fpi_img_new()` . Here is the syntax for that function

```
struct fp_img *fpi_img_new(size_t length);
```

but when I try to allocate some memory by passing the value to this function it shows the following error

```
GLib-ERROR **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.30.0/./glib/gmem.c:170: failed to allocate 3078340616 bytes
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/bin/java: line 31:  3078 Trace/breakpoint trap   $jre $args
```

I am passing the value manually to just check the functionality of this function.But it gets fail.
Could any one please help me in solving the above problem?
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT :**

Here is my code where i am using the fpi_img_new() function :

```
API_EXPORTED struct fp_img *fpi_img_new(size_t length)
{
    struct fp_img *img = g_malloc(sizeof(*img) + length);
    memset(img, 0, sizeof(*img));
    fp_dbg("length=%zd", length);
    img->length = length;
    return img;
}
```

And i am calling this function by simply passing the integer value like

```
fpi_img_new(2)
```

Comment: Not sure but [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187529/glib-memory-allocation-error) link may help.