# Glib memory allocation error

Tags: java, c, glib, memset

I am using a library [libfprint](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/libfprint/) on ubuntu nd I am trying to call a function through my java code.

```
API_EXPORTED struct fp_img *fpi_img_new(size_t length)
{
    struct fp_img *img = g_malloc(sizeof(*img) + length);
    memset(img, 0, sizeof(*img));
    fp_dbg("length=%zd", length);
    img->length = length;
    return img;
}
```

I am passing integer value 5 from my java code to this function. When I try to execute above function I got following errors:

```
GLib-ERROR **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.30.0/./glib/gmem.c:170: failed to allocate 3077591024 bytes
```

I have tried same code on 2 different ubuntu machine but the error remains the same. I dont know why it is trying to allocate so many bytes for 24+5 length.

Could anyone suggest me any solution?

Comment: Look like there is a dereferencing missing. Like if you had `size_t *` instead.

Comment: no.. size_t is an int type. If i use size_t * it gives error on comilation.

Comment: Of course you need to dereference it with `*length`. Let me post you an answer

Comment: I predict that someone made a cast when calling this function to avoid an error. I also predict that the code is either full of warnings that someone ignored or warnings are disabled. Pay attention to the warnings and only add type casts when you are *positive* that you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

[The source code](http://www.reactivated.net/fprint/api/fprint_8h-source.html) clearly states:

```
/* structs that applications are not allowed to peek into */
(...)
struct fp_img;
```

So, I'm not sure what you did in order to even compile something that needs the size of `struct fp_img`: you're not supposed to be able to do that, since the structure declaration is opaque.

Comment: I don't think this would address the issue but on the other hand it clearly shows that the way of allocating the fp_img is not the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

It look like you get a pointer instead of a `size_t`.
Try to change your definition to:

```
API_EXPORTED struct fp_img *fpi_img_new(size_t * length);
```

You then need to derefenrece it:

```
API_EXPORTED struct fp_img *fpi_img_new(size_t * length)
{
    struct fp_img *img = g_malloc(sizeof(*img) + *length);
    memset(img, 0, sizeof(*img));
    fp_dbg("length=%zd", *length);
    img->length = *length;
    return img;
}
```

Note: It seems that 3077591024 is on the stack (0x125807FE) it is highly platform dependent so don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change

```
sizeof(*img)
```

with

```
sizeof(struct fp_img)
```

? I'm thinking that this could be your problem because *img is not initialised to anything at the time you are calling g_malloc().

Comment: -1, `sizeof` for this expression is computed at compile-time, and therefore doesn't depend on whether or not the argument is "initialized".

Answer (score -1):

**ERROR: struct fp_img *img = g_malloc(sizeof(*img) + length);**

*img is new created, so you can not use it like "sizeof(*img)", 
you could write like this: "sizeof(struct fp_img)"

Comment: `sizeof(*img)` is fine. As state by @unwind it is a builtin function evaluated at compile time. Try it with your compiler before saying non-sense.